# how essentially g1 gc guarantee low latency pause?

Tags: garbage-collection, jvm, latency, g1gc

I looked online. But most of the docs just mentioned because g1 gc is incremental, predicatble collection without much details.

Comment: 1) G1 does not guaranee pause time. 2) G1 *tries* to satisfy the desired pause time by careful selection of heap regions to collect. Most phases of G1 mixed collection (except initial mark and remark) are concurrent, i. e. they do not need to pause application at all.

Answer (score 1):

"incremental" means it can stop at any time (within reason) so it stops once the threshold has been reached.

None of the GCs can guarantee how long it takes, but some have the option to take the target pause time into account and resize the regions or stop early as G1 does.